# How to incorporate progressbar on loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops, datareader

Hi I'm kinda new with the progress bar, therefore I wasn't sure how could a incorporate it on my loop. What I'am trying to do is that in every loop, the progress bar will increment its value or progress on how much percentage does my function has already done. Appreciate if you could help me add some codes here. Thank you very much in advance.

here's the loop I'am working on:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.Read()
        DataTableName = TextBox1.Text
        ID1 = reader.Item("MotorSN").ToString
        ID2 = reader.Item("StationNo").ToString
        ID3 = reader.Item("WU_NestNo").ToString
        ID4 = reader.Item("PT_TimeIn").ToString
        ID5 = reader.Item("PT_NestNo").ToString
        ID6 = reader.Item("PT_Q_Std_Bellmouth_0").ToString
        ID7 = ""
        ID8 = ""
        ID9 = ""
        ID10 = ""
        ID11 = ""
        ID12 = ""
        Note1 = ""
        Note2 = ""
        sDate = ""
        sTime = ""
        wd = S2K_SetDataTableVariableValue(DataTableName, dValue, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, ID9, ID10, ID11, ID12, Note1, Note2, sDate, sTime)
    End While

    MessageBox.Show("Data has been written To the table")
End If
```

Comment: Did my answer work or provide help?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to one I implemented, its quite easy.

- 1.Place your progress bar somewhere on your form.

  2. above your for loop add in a count of rows in your datatbale so something like `datatable.rows.count` or similar
  3. apply it to a variable and then write `ProgressBar1.Maximum = datatablerowcount`
  4. Set the size of a step to 1 on your progress bar `ProgressBar1.Step = 1`
  5. Then simply add just before your `end while` add in this `ProgressBar1.PerformStep()`

What this basically does is, sets the full value of the progress bar to amount of items you have to read through, then gets 1 step closer to that max with each row read.

**edit**

```
Dim row_count As Integer = datatable.Rows.Count '(or however you can)
ProgressBar1.Maximum = row_count 
ProgressBar1.Step = 1

If reader.HasRows Then 
    While reader.Read()
        DataTableName = TextBox1.Text
        ID1 = reader.Item("MotorSN").ToString
        ID2 = reader.Item("StationNo").ToString
        ID3 = reader.Item("WU_NestNo").ToString
        ID4 = reader.Item("PT_TimeIn").ToString
        ID5 = reader.Item("PT_NestNo").ToString
        ID6 = reader.Item("PT_Q_Std_Bellmouth_0").ToString
        ID7 = ""
        ID8 = ""
        ID9 = ""
        ID10 = ""
        ID11 = ""
        ID12 = ""
        Note1 = ""
        Note2 = ""
        sDate = ""
        sTime = ""
        wd = S2K_SetDataTableVariableValue(DataTableName, dValue, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, ID9, ID10, ID11, ID12, Note1, Note2, sDate, sTime)

        progressbar1.performstep()
    End While

    MessageBox.Show("Data has been written To the table")
End If
```

**EDIT**
Not 100% sure what your reading from etc. But yeah just get a row count of whatever your reading from with the reader and set it as `row_count`